# How can I update the php5-cli package on this Linux distribution?

Tags: php, version, command-line-interface

I have a godaddy shared hosting account

I don't know what distribution is my account using.
So, I ran the **uname -a** command and here is the response:-

```
Linux a2plcpnl0006.prod.iad2.secureserver.net 2.6.32-    531.29.2.lve1.3.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 18 06:49:17 EST 2014 x86_64     x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

running the php -v command gives the following output:-

```
PHP 5.4.43 (cli) (built: Jul 23 2015 20:40:13)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.7.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

and running **php-cgi -v** command gives the following result:-

```
PHP 5.5.24 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Apr 20 2015 06:24:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

I want to update the php-cli package to version 5

Thanks.

Comment: For who are giving the question negative voting ?? Can you tell me WHY ???? or you can ONLY VOTE NEGATIVELY ?!

Comment: Read the error.  Its VERY clear

Comment: you just need to update the php , nothing else..

Comment: I know its clear, how can I update the PHP Version to overcome the laravel updgrade problem ?
The php CLI version is not 5.4 ? I want it to be 5.5 like the CGI version as updating laravel is done from the CLI

Comment: i think there is no valid reason to give you down votes. It would have been better if negative voters first pointed out the problem. I see no issue here. +1 for asking.

Comment: That is the point :)
Big thanks for you.

Comment: you can't change your hosts php version.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is very clear. Laravel requires php 5.5.9 version or higher. You have two options:

1. Update your `php5-cli` package
2. Run `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`. It will update your packages without checking your php version.

Comment: How can I update the php5-cli package on this Linux distribution ?
The followin is the output of uname -a command

Linux a2plcpnl0006.prod.iad2.secureserver.net 2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 18 06:49:17 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @HazemTaha try `yum install php5-cli`

Comment: are you surprised your shared host wont let you change the php version installed?